# Spring Request Mapping URL's to One Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have asked a recent question regarding a similar urls mapping to the same controller.
In this case I had to give it 3 or 4 urls which is fine.

[Spring Request Mapping Mis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559209/spring-request-mapping-mis)

The example contained the following.

`@RequestMapping({"/protect", "/protekt", "/proteckt", "/protext"})`

My issue now is there are 100-150 urls that weill essentially go through ONE controller. These URL's are to be contained in a database. I am looking for an elegant way to maintain this in the Request Mapping rather than putting 100 different URLS(that may change) particularly because the client I am working for doesn't want to make any changes to the back end. Is there an elegant way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I'd probably start by looking at ways to provide a [`SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.html) subclass that grabbed its list of values from the DB. It's pretty straight-forward, keeps you from having to hook into any scanning, and keeps the configuration pretty localized to one chunk of XML (plus DB stuff).

(I think you only *need* to implement a [`HandlerMapping`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerMapping.html) but it might be quicker to start from a `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`--that'll be tomorrow's test hack for me.)

You don't say whether or not these URLs need to change at runtime; if they do then you'd need the ability to hook in at a deeper level to update the actual mappings--not sure how to do that off the top of my head.